# How do I force Powershell to review the output of a command and wait for it to complete

Tags: powershell

I am using the Netapp powershell module for ONTAP to create and split storage LUN clones into individual volumes. The split process takes approximately 1.5 hours, and I want PS to wait until the split process is complete before moving to the next function in my script.

While the split is running, the output of the split status command looks like this:

BlockPercentageComplete: 79
Blocks Scanned: 23452345
Blocks Updated: 213452345

Once the split process has completed, the split status command returns nothing.

How can I tell powershell to review this output and only move to the next steps in the script when the output is blank?

Comment: add a `while` loop that tests for "something there" and has a `Start-Sleep` delay in the loop.

Comment: Consider adding appropriate tags so that the correct users can find it.   This may be a question more appropriate for a different over-flow.

Comment: Could be something like `$result = Get-OnTAPfunction, while ($result -ne $null) {write-output $result; $result = Get-OnTAPfunction}`.

Comment: Did something similar for Exchange Mailbox moves. Works like a charm.

Comment: the result = looks like it is working, but it will take a while for the job to complete.  Could I do while ($result -ne $null) {sleep - seconds 60} ?